# PHP: analyse variable

Tags: php, variables

I am creating a website for school.

I have the subjects of a student saved in a database.

It's get saved like this -->    1,2,3,6,7

This means student X does subject ID 1,2,3, 6 and 7

The subjects from one student get returned from a database in one variable $subjects
I would like to output the Subject Name (subject names are also stored in the database).
But since the variable that is returned in $subjects is not one subject, but multiple, I can't search for the subject name. Is it possible to convert $subjects to an array so that $subjects[0] would be 1 in my example and $subjects[1] would be 2 (see above @ it's get saved like this).

Simply said:
it should not be
$subjects = 1,2,3,6,7
but

```
$subjects[0] = 1
$subjects[1] = 2
$subjects[2] = 3
$subjects[3] = 6
$subjects[4] = 7
```

Comment: [`explode()`](http://de2.php.net/explode)

Comment: You can get the database itself to give out the names directly, but for this to happen you must normalize the schema by creating a join table for the N-to-M relationship between students and subjects. Google a bit.

Comment: @Carsten That seems to do it! Thanks man!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to convert a string to an array:

```
explode(',', $students);
```

It should be noted, however, that exploding and then doing more queries to your database to get the subject names is a very inefficient way to do this. Rather that store students subjects in one field you should create a whole table for that relationship. So in additional to a Students table and a Subjects table, you have the relationship:

Table: StudentSubjects

```
Student | Subject
-----------------
   1    |   1
   1    |   2
   1    |   3
   1    |   6
   1    |   7
   2    |   2
   2    |   4
   2    |   6
   2    |   8
   3    |   3
```

Then you can query your database and get a list of subject names for a particular student, or group of students, in one query.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose 2 way:

explode :

```
<?php
$str = '1,2,3,6,7';
$chars = explode(',', $str);
print_r($chars);
?>
```

or preg_split:

```
<?php
$str = '1,2,3,6,7';
$chars = preg_split('/,/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($chars);
?>
```

Comment: There is no reason to use preg_split when explode will suffice.